# Programmatically create a trigger within abnormally shaped room

Tags: unity, 3d

So I'm trying to create a trigger in each of my rooms. These rooms can be created by players. Basically, I need to know all the objects in a room. These rooms can be shaped in weird and wonderful ways. I'm struggling to figure out how to "fill" an area? The other problem is that some walls are curved.

My current thinking is:

- Loop over all the walls in a scene. Do 4 raycasts from each side of the wall and see if we hit other walls. If we do, we are likely in a room.
- From the offset, literally check each node adjacent to that until we fill the room. Once I have this though, Im not sure what to do with it.

How do I create bounds that I can check for collisions with this data?

Edit: Adding an image for clarity. Red and blue should be 2 different rooms and I want to get all items in each of these rooms

[image]

Comment: Can you give us any information about how your players make these rooms? There's a good chance we can use the structure of the creation system to simplify our work. For instance, we don't need to handle any edge cases that your creation method is incapable of producing. Also, for any kind of geometric question, a screenshot or diagram can go a long way to ensuring others are visualizing the same situation you have in mind.

Comment: @DMGregory updated with a picture. The tooling for making these rooms feels very much like Unity's scene editor.

Comment: Do you have any constraints that the corner of a wall must touch another wall, or that walls can't cross?

Comment: @DMGregory There are no constraints

Comment: So, can we reduce your question to: "Determine the closed polygons formed by a collection of line segments in the 2D plane" ?

Comment: @DMGregory Sure, that can work I guess, but that leads to my 2nd point of "How do I then check what intersects these bounds?"

Comment: Once we've built polygons from our rooms, then that reduces to a simple point-in-polygon test, does it not?

Comment: So I guess then my question is how do I determine the closed polygons formed by a collection of line segments in the 2D plane :)

Comment: Searching for "polygons from line segments" leads me to [resources like this](http://ac.aua.am/sergey_yeranosyan/Web/algorithm%20project/) - have you tried applying techniques like this to your case?